# Need help getting oracle "SORT BY" to work how I want it to

Tags: html, sql, oracle, asp-classic

I've got a table that's full of data, and it has five columns: id(varchar2), description(varchar2), diameter(number), crown(number), and lockout(single char)

The table is built into a webapp made using ASP-classic.  The table has a row at the top with headers that have the names of each column.  When the user clicks the heading, the table rebuilds, sorting by the column that they clicked either ascending or descending, depending on what the previous direction was (like your typical sort button on a website).

What I want to happen is:  When the user clicks *any row other than id*, sort by the row they clicked ***and*** by id, because there can be hundreds of records with the same value for description, for example.

Here is my snippet of code that determines how to sort, right now.

```
if Len(strSort) > 0 then
    sqlQry = sqlQry + " ORDER BY " & strSort
    if intSortDir <> "1" then
        sqlQry = sqlQry + " DESC"
    end if
end if
```

`strSort` is pulled from the asp query url and is added to the url when it is clicked.  `intSortDir` basically is initialized to 0 and toggles when the user clicks a heading.

To summarize, my question is, how can I sort by two columns at once, with the one being clicked being the primary sort.

I tried this:

```
if Len(strSort) > 0 then
    if strSort = "id" then 
        sqlQry = sqlQry + " ORDER BY " & strSort
        if intSortDir <> "1" then
            sqlQry = sqlQry + " DESC"
        end if
    else
        sqlQry = sqlQry + " ORDER BY " & strSort & ",id"
        if intSortDir <> "1" then
            sqlQry = sqlQry + " DESC"
        end if
    end if
end if
```

And it sort of sorted the way I wanted it to, but it wouldn't let me toggle the sort direction.

Comment: Try ORDER BY <Column> <SORT-DIRECTION>

Comment: This looks like what you're doing to build the queries will be vulnerable to sql injection attacks. tsk tsk

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I heard that yesterday too when I was having issues.  How can I avoid that?

Not that I'm super worried, because it'll only be running on the intranet and not publicly accessible, but still

Comment: Parameterized queries.

Comment: Okay, good to know.  How could I make it so the query can be variable without parameterizing it?  This is a great learning experience for me.  Would I just make a massive switch statement so that if strSort is this, do this query, and if it's that, do that query?  That seems like it would be a mess because there could be thousands of potential queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if Len(strSort) > 0 then
    sqlQry = sqlQry + " ORDER BY " & strSort 
    if intSortDir <> "1" then
        sqlQry = sqlQry + " DESC"
    end if

    if strSort <> "id" then 
        sqlQry = sqlQry + ", id"
        if intSortDir <> "1" then
            sqlQry = sqlQry + " DESC"
        end if
    end if
end if
```

Also, you may have better luck using javascript to sort these rows in the browser. If you can use jQuery, there is a tablesorter() plugin that makes it easy.

Comment: This does the same thing as the second snippet of code that I posted.  It sorts by the primary row and then also by `id`, but if I click the primary row again, it flips the order of `id`.  I need it to reorder by the primary row again.

Comment: Alright, this fixed it.  Thank you very much!  I'll look into jQuery, as well, but your solution fixed it